# Can python detect which key is used on keyboard regardless of keyboard layout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qwerty

On the english keyboard 'y' is in the same place as 'z' on the slovenian keyboard (AZERTY). Is there a way a Python program can identify which physical key was pressed when you press the same key regardless of the language that is used?

Comment: You'll need to specify how you're receiving the input: are you using a UI framework (which?), a game framework (which?), or the command-line?

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand you're asking about running commands in the Python REPL (AKA shell). AFAIK the Python REPL doesn't interact directly with hardware; instead it interacts with OS libraries. In this case that means it doesn't receive key scancodes but characters. So instead of trying to change Python, change the keyboard layout of  your OS. How to do that depends on the OS.